# How to Specify Bootstrap Version for Shoreditch?

Tags: theme, shoreditch, bootstrap

I've been running D7 & D9 sites with a bootstrap 3 theme + CiviCRM with Shoreditch.  Works Great!  Need to consider using the Drupal Bootstrap Barrio theme ( bootstrap 4 or bootstrap 5) ... but if I install these in Drupal then Shoreditch doesn't function properly (wrong display sizes, not scrollable, check boxes not clickable,etc).  Reverting to plain Bootstrap 3 cures the issue.

How can I force Shoreditch to use Bootstrap 3 while the Drupal front-end uses its own version of Bootstrap (4,5)?